# How can I unmarshall feign xml response and get tags namespace value?

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, feign, decoder

For example with this xml response:

```
 <header xmlns=".." dateResponse="202208282016" status="0" id="1119840"/>
```

The value I actually need is the id. Is there some sort of a feign decoder that could detect the id and give me the value or do I have to write my custom decoder using something like xPath?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jaxb library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then create a pojo and add @XmlRootElement:

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement //neccessary for mapping
public class ResponseB {
    private String msg;
}
```

and feign endpoint:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/b", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    ResponseB getIDsB();
```